# is it possible to demo an iPhone app on an iPad?

Tags: iphone, ipad, xamarin.ios

my project involves creation of an app that is just for mobile use, we have been given iPads for demoing the app. is it possible to display the app on the iPad but as though it is an iPhone ? the scaling does not look the way I want it to on iPad.

Comment: Yes, as long as it does not use any phone specific features (like dialing a number).  Be sure that "Device Family" in info.plist is set to iPhone, not iPad or Universal.

Comment: define "the scaling does not look the way I want it" - do you want the standard iPhone only app on iPad look ? or something else ?

Comment: @Jason I just tried the way you mentioned, their is a few scaling issues / bugs such as buttons being out of place and text not being visible but it seems like a good start thanks

Comment: @WarrenBurton I would like it to look like when it displays on any model of iPhone from 5-x , I have tested it on all those devices and on my personal iPhone 7 and it works the way I want it , when testing on iPad it breaks my custom UI

Comment: please post an image demonstrating the problem

Comment: @Jason sorry I would but I am not allowed to due to the constraints of the project, I should be able to go from here though , I think its to do with the constraints on one of the buttons and then just resizing the text windows , thanks for your help